# Jquery mobile load external page and keep it

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im trying to load an external jquery mobile page into my main page with:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "./pages/test1/test1.html", {});
```

and i want to keep it in the dom, even when im going back from that page.

Is there a way to do that? becouse when back key is presses, the page is removed from the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at setting `data-dom-cache="true"` on the page:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/page/#option-domCache

This will keep loaded pages in the DOM.

Comment: changed to $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "./pages/test1/test1.html", {domCache: true}); still doesnt work

Comment: did you try adding data-dom-cache="true" to the data-role="page" DIV?